# ng-file-upload + sending multiple file array empty to server (sails)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to send multiple files to my sails server using ng-file-upload . I'm using the example of ng-file-upload's webpage, and it does not work.

**Problem:**

I get an empty array at the server.

**Facts:**

I am using chrome and it has html5 multiple file upload support.

I tested the server using postman and it worked, that being said, the problem is with the client.

I'm able to console.log the files at the client.

Here is the js code:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function (files) {
         if (!($scope.updateAssetForm.OSGImages)) {
             console.log($scope.updateAsset.OSGImages.$valid);
             console.log($scope.updateAssetForm.OSGImages);
             return;
         }
        console.log($scope.updateAssetForm.OSGImages);
        var test = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.updateAssetForm.OSGImages.length; i++) {
            test.push($scope.updateAssetForm.OSGImages[i])
        }
        console.log(test);


                Upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/updateAsset',
                    data: {
                         osgFile: test,
                        'assetId': 5,
                        'loadValueType' : 4,
                    }
                })


    },
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div class = "control-group form-group col-md-12"
    ng-class = "{'has-error':updateAsset.OSGImages.$invalid && updateAsset.OSGImages.$dirty}" ng-if = "showUploadFile(4)">
      <button ngf-select="onFileSelect(updateAssetForm.OSGImages)" ng-model="updateAssetForm.OSGImages" ngf-multiple="true">
      OSG Images (optional) (max 3 MB) 
      </div>
      <p ng-repeat="image in updateAssetForm.OSGImages">
        {{image.name}}
      </p>
      <span class = "help-block has-error" ng-if="updateAsset.OSGImages.$dirty">
      </span>
    </div>
```

**Network Tab log:**

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Origin:http://localhost:1337
Referer:http://localhost:1337/editproject
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="osgFile[0]"; filename="p51d-jw-03.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="osgFile[1]"; filename="p51d-jw-02.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="osgFile[2]"; filename="p51d-jw-01.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="assetId"

5
------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="loadValueType"

4
------WebKitFormBoundaryhfBw31xYfdWDtTlU--

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation references `$files` when you make a call to your function.  Have you tried passing `$files` instead of `updateAssetForm.OSGImages` into `onFileSelect()`?

Comment: The documentation references $files because it is using ng-model = "files". I 'm using ng-model = "updateAssetForm.OSGImages"

Comment: what's your request look like in network tab?

Comment: --> edited original post

Comment: They are being send. The network tab won't show the binary content of the file but it is there.

Comment: then why the server is getting an empty array?

Comment: Found the problem. Answer is below

Answer (score 4):

Add the arrayKey: ' ' field to your Upload function

```
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/updateAsset',          
        arrayKey: '',
        data: {
                osgFile: test,
                'assetId': 5,
                'loadValueType' : 4,
              },
        method: "PUT"
      })
```

It will make sure that the array of files are received with "fieldName" instead of "fieldName[0]"

Answer (score 0):

I found the "problem":

ng-file-upload changes the "name"(of the field) to "name[0]", "name[1]", "name[n]"... I was trying to get all the array at the server with "name".

The reason why I was trying to get all the array with "name" is because when I send the array with postman it gets all the array using just "name".

The solution for avoiding array problem when uploading multiple files with sails + ng-file-upload is here: 
https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/67

best.